# Multi-client RPC routing daemon

Tags: client-server, rpc

I've spent a few weeks looking for a daemon that is capable of the following:

- Handling arbitrary numbers of clients from other network hosts.
- Allowing clients to register services under an identity.
- Allowing other clients to make RPC calls to these registered services, with reliable error handling (if client registered for that service detaches, the daemon should report an error to the caller, not leave it hanging).
- Allowing clients to register to receive events, which other clients can broadcast.
- The simpler, the better.

The closest thing I've found in the F/LOSS world is D-Bus, which meets all of these criteria except the first: it cannot reliably work with remote connections.  I have spent time looking into other options (ESB and MQ daemons -- spending the most time with 0MQ and RabbitMQ) and they all fall short in one way or another: ESBs tend to be extremely complicated with a high learning curve, and MQ daemons tend to provide half of the solution (routing) while leaving the other half (error recovery) extremely complicated, if not impossible.

I'm not looking for any fantastic routing capabilities beyond one client saying "I provide service 'foo'" and another client saying "I want to invoke method 'bar' on service 'foo'."

It seems like something like this would exist already, and I hesitate to roll my own.

The use case is that I will have many processes across many hosts.  Each host will have a governor process/service that will provide control of the lifetimes of these processes from a control panel.  The processes themselves will also be services, allowing for direct inquiry about status as well as reconfiguration requests from this panel.  The trick is that processes will come and go, and so static configuration of endpoints isn't something I really want to bother with; I would rather have each process be responsible for telling a daemon "I'm service so-and-so" and then let the daemon do the inter-client routing.

The only piece I'm really missing to develop this system is something that can route RPC requests between all of these processes.  Is there any such daemon out there, or is there some other model that would better fit my needs?

Comment: this is an old question!  did you get anywhere? I've been using autobahn for this sort of thing.  It lets me register methods in one client, and then call the method from another client without knowing where the 'service' is being performed.

Comment: @Greg I haven't really gotten much further than I had before asking this question. (I've had other projects come up that superseded this one.) However, I fear that this question would now be considered off-topic since it's asking for a recommendation of an off-site resource. :|

Comment: @Greg +1 for Autobahn though, it looks like it might fit the bill nicely.